# How to create angularjs custom directive for google location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive to lookup google locations using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>` like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('locationPicker', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        template: '<input id="{{id}}" type="text" class="{{class}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            class: '@',
            placeholder: '@',
        },
        link: function ($scope, elm, attrs, controller) {

            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elm[0], {types: ['geocode']});

            var componentForm = {
                locality: 'long_name',
                administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
                country: 'long_name'
            };

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

                var name = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                        if (name !== "") {
                            name += ", ";
                        }

                        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                        name += val;
                    }
                }

                elm[0].value = name;
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    controller.$setViewValue({name: name, lat: lat, lng: lng});
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And my input:

```
<input id="location" location-picker ng-model="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Project location" ng-required="true" />
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.location = {
   name:null,
   lat:null,
   lng:null
};
```

Everything looks fine but when my component is first rendered, the value of the input is [Object object] instead of the place holder (Project Location).

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: yes because you model name is `location` and its a object in the controller

Comment: You can try `location.name` instead of `location`

Comment: But the whole point of using an object is to be able to fetch lat and lng when the location is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You are binding `ngModel` to the location object, which renders as `[object Object]` when coerced to a string.

#### Solution

Since you are grabbing hold of the `NgModelController` in your directive, you can use its [$formatters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) pipeline to transform the model value (location object with `name`, `lat`, `lng` properties) into the view value and the [$render](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render) function to specify how to render the value if it is changed outside of the `ngModel` lifecycle.

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5HPFelbDFUrzeccGfgYx?p=preview. The crucial piece of code is

```
// triggered by $setViewValue
controller.$formatters.push(function (value) {
    return value ? value.name : value;
});

// triggered by clear() from controller
controller.$render = function () {
    input.value = controller.$modelValue.name;
};
```

I have also made the following modifications to your code:

1. Used `location-picker` as an element directive. `input` is not a good choice of element since it already has bindings to `ngModel`.
2. Removed `replace: true`. It is a deprecated configuration option in directives, and can cause some strange behaviors, since it tries to mix attributes of directive element and attributes of template element.
3. Removed `elm[0].value = name;`. This is handled by the lifecycle of the `ngModel` when you call `$setViewValue`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've made only one small change and it worked like a charm: element[0].removeAttribute('class'); & element[0].removeAttribute('id');